# class member values are zero after a return to calling method

Tags: c#, methods

I am experimenting(First timer!) with external assemblies, and whenever I call a method from my external assembly I get all empty data... here are some snippits:
External assembly called like this:

```
        FileOps.Outs O = new FileOps.Outs();
        FileOps.ReadFile(LOC); // LOC = Filepath
        foreach (string S in O.FileContainer) // O.FileContainer is List<string>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(S); // Prints Nothing
        }
```

Readfile() method in assembly:

```
    public static Outs ReadFile(string LOC)
    {
        Outs O = new Outs();

        if (File.Exists(LOC))
        {

            foreach (string S in File.ReadLines(LOC))
            {
                O.FileContainer.Add(S);
            }
            O.Baal = true;
        }
        else
        {
            //O.Baal = false;
            //O.FileContainer.Contains(null);
            File.Create(LOC).Close();
            string Header =  "Useless text data here\n," + "Users:\n,";
            O.FileContainer = new List<string>(Header.Split(O.Csep, StringSplitOptions.None)); //Csep is char[] {','}
            foreach (string S in O.FileContainer)
            {
                File.AppendAllText(LOC, S);
            }
        }
        return O;
    }
```

Class used to store info:

```
public class Outs
    {
    public bool Baal { get; set; }
    public List<string>FileContainer { get; set; }
    public char[] Csep;
        public Outs()
        {
            Baal = false;
            FileContainer = new List<string>();
            Csep = new char[] { ',' };
        }
    }
```

Upon returning to calling method all values are 0 or null... I have set a breakpoint and went through the code line by line.  Prior to returning all data is good... any thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `FileOps.Outs O = FileOps.ReadFile(LOC);`?

Comment: Coming up with real [MCVE] is always good idea... So far it looks like "typographical error" - missing assignment of function call to the `O` variable... Possibly you don't know how to use functions in C# - reading book/MSDN may be better option.

Comment: @Jen format that into an answer, and I will accept it.

Comment: @Alexei The suggestion about reading may help some, but there are people that learn better/faster by doing. [Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_styles)  That being said I do appreciate your input! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
FileOps.Outs O = new FileOps.Outs();
FileOps.ReadFile(LOC); // LOC = Filepath
```

Try this:

```
FileOps.Outs O = FileOps.ReadFile(LOC);
```

It's a static method that returns an instance. The caller isn't meant to use `new` to create their own instance.

If you are in control of the `FileOps` class, you can prevent the caller from making this mistake by marking the constructor private, e.g.

```
public class Outs
{
    private Outs()
    {
        //etc.
```

This way, the static method `ReadFile` has the ability to create a FileOps (because it is a member of the class), but nobody outside of the class can instantiate one. This is a pretty common pattern.